# Parse XML file from SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xml-parsing

Hi I tried to parse the XML file from SQL. But the path seems cannot find the data. I am not sure if the path is correct. Below is the sample xml file I have:

```
   if OBJECT_ID('temp') is not null
drop table temp


CREATE TABLE temp (data xml);
insert into temp values
(' <Services>
    <Service Name="AlternativeCreditAttributes">
      <Categories>
        <Category Name="Default">
          <Attributes>
             <Attribute Name="ACA_TOF_Days_Since_LAST_PAYMENT" Value="15" />
          </Attributes>
        </Category>
      </Categories>
    </Service>
  </Services>
');
GO
```

And below is my `data.value` code:

```
SELECT data.value('(Services/Service [@Name="AlternativeCreditAttributes"]/Categories/Category[@Name="Default"]/Attributes/Attribute[@Name="ACA_TOF_Days_Since_LAST_PAYMENT"])[1]', 'varchar(100)')
FROM   temp;
GO
```

Comment: Are you trying to select `15`?

Comment: What is your desired output?

Answer (score 0):

As you correctly stated, your *XPath* is completely off. Here is as a starting point, the `@Value` attribute retrieval.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, xml_data XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl (xml_data)
VALUES ('<Services>
    <Service Name="AlternativeCreditAttributes">
      <Categories>
        <Category Name="Default">
          <Attributes>
             <Attribute Name="ACA_TOF_Days_Since_LAST_PAYMENT" Value="15" />
          </Attributes>
        </Category>
      </Categories>
    </Service>
  </Services>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT col.value('(@Value)[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS [Value]
FROM @tbl AS tbl
    CROSS APPLY tbl.xml_data.nodes('/Services/Service[@Name="AlternativeCreditAttributes"]/Categories/Category[@Name="Default"]/Attributes/Attribute[@Name="ACA_TOF_Days_Since_LAST_PAYMENT"]') AS tab(col);
```

**Output**

```
+-------+
| Value |
+-------+
|    15 |
+-------+
```